# How to repeat a function five times?

Tags: r, loops, repeat

I have a formula and want to repeat it five times, would you mind to help me?
the loop is as follow:

```
ED_Dry= e.divisive(X=Rainfall_Dry,sig.lvl=0.05,R=199,k=NULL,min.size=20,alpha=1)

repeat {
  ED_Annuall= e.divisive(X=Rainfall_annuall,sig.lvl=0.05,R=199,k=NULL,min.size=20,alpha=1)
  if(ED_Annuall$p.values<0.05) {
    print("End of Loop");
    break
  }
  time(5)
}# end of if
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:5){
  ED_Annuall=e.divisive(X=Rainfall_annuall,sig.lvl=0.05,R=199,k=NULL,min.size=20,alpha=1)
  if(ED_Annuall$p.values<0.05) {
    print("End of Loop");
    break
  }
}
```

Isn't this enough?

Comment: I think time(5) should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
ED_Dry= e.divisive(X=Rainfall_Dry,sig.lvl=0.05,R=199,k=NULL,min.size=20,alpha=1)
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   ED_Annuall= e.divisive(X=Rainfall_annuall,sig.lvl=0.05,R=199,k=NULL,min.size=20,alpha=1)
   if(ED_Annuall$p.values<0.05) {
      print("End of Loop");
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is for loop in C. The question, judging from the tag, is in R.